# How do C compilers provide access to several memories?

Tags: compiler-construction

If a computer has more than one address space which is used for data, how have C compilers provided access to these?

### The context

Some real-life architectures I am thinking about:

**KR580VM1** or **КР580ВМ1**

This is basically an Intel 8080 with the addition of a few registers and a 17th address line. An instruction prefix asserts the 17th address line after the opcode is fetched until the instruction ends; since a pointer is still only 16 bits wide, this naturally divides the address space in two halves. The lower half of the address space may contain code and both halves may contain data.

**The peripheral processors of the CDC 6000**

These have a 12-bit address bus and can therefore access 4096 machine words of local memory. They also have an 18-bit address bus for addressing a central memory bank.

**Cell Processor**

These are used in the PlayStation 3 and from what I understand have a similar arrangement to the CDC I mentioned. I'm not sure, but I think the SPEs' address spaces may overlap the PPE's.

### The questions

In my head, a pointer is something which kind of looks like an integer since it has discrete values and can count up or down, and it is something which will eventually be put on the address bus. My problem is that for the architectures I described, for various reasons, a pointer does not uniquely identify a memory location. This means that a code generator will need to be concerned in a different way about how to generate the code to dereference a pointer.

So is there an implementation of a C compiler which concerns itself with this problem? Can you describe their solution to me?

Comment: Sorry why did you tag C ? What is the link with the C language ? This has nothing to do with C

Comment: @Stargateur I am interested in C particularly. The solution in C will be completely different from a solution in, say, Lisp. But I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I did not downvote, but your question lacks motivation and context, and is perhaps not suitable on StackOveflow (too broad, without any [MCVE]). Please **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: A pointer can count up and down **only within the distinct object or just past it**.

Comment: (which naturally includes arrays)

Comment: Your question is about C implementation not C itself. I'm an expert in C and I can't answer your question. Stop think that C is assembly, cause C is not. Ask for a specific compiler and system but don't tag C as it doesn't concern C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler provides *as an extension* [named address spaces](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html) (and also [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes), [variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes), [type attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes), [target-specific builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Target-Builtins.html), ...). This is probably useful in your context. Sometimes, you have other kind of extensions (e.g. [far pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer) on old 16 bits PCs...)

Details are compiler and target architecture specific.

You might even extend GCC with your own GCC [plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (this is not easy).

But, the CDC6000 predated C by a long time.

In some cases, the co-processors are getting their own programs and the data transfers are explicit. Look into [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) for an example.

In other cases, specific `#pragma`s are guiding the compiler. See [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC).

Of course, you could just have an API for shared memory. See for example [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html).

Sometimes, you might have strange [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s. Look into [x32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) for example.

At last, C is not as universal as you want it to be. Some architectures don't fit well into it.

Comment: Why the downvote? It provides an answer to the question.

Comment: I think so too, especially these later edits. You got a +1 from me to counter it.

Comment: I agree as well: this does answer the question. At most, one might add to it. For example: Atmel AVR is a [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture), with separate address spaces for code (flash) and RAM. Read-only data is put into Flash with help from the linker (`PROGMEM` attribute). In general, separate functions are written to access the different address spaces. (In avr-libc, Flash-accessing functions have a `_P` suffix. Actual low-level address-space specific access, like `pgm_read_byte()`, is implemented either via compiler-built-ins, or inline assembly.)

Answer (score 1):

Without listing all these exotic architectures, this is a fairly common situation for 8/16 bit microcontrollers that need to address more flash memory than the 64kib that their 16 bit address bus would allow. MS DOS + early x86 had similar problems.

There's two possible solutions, neither is good:

- Compile all pointers in the program for the larger address range. This will make the binary size much bigger, and will possibly also affect performance.
- Use non-standard extensions for different address areas, such as non-standard `near` pointers for accessing the smaller addresses and `far` for the larger ones. That is, `near` and `far` becomes non-standard type qualifiers for pointers: `int* far ptr;`